# Why does an SQL query work through PHPMySQLAdmin but not through mysql_query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The query is:

```
 SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Production AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN Estimates ON
 p.EstId=Estimates.EstId WHERE p.DocketNumber=20227
```

When I enter literally this query into PHPMySQLAdmin, it executes and gives me a result. When I enter this query into PHP code, it brings up an error. There is no problem connecting to the database, because when I remove COUNT and the brackets around *, the query executes.

Is this an issue with mysql and conflicts with the count command?

EDIT: nvm

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: do you get the error (what error exactly ?) also if you remove the space between COUNT and (*) ?

Comment: I assume you mean phpMyAdmin?

Comment: `mysql_error()` should tell you if there's a problem with the query.

Comment: @Michael Mior yes
@Scorpi PHP code is if(!mysql_query($link, $query)) echo "Query failed - " . $query; Where the query is stored in the $query variable

Comment: But running `mysql_error()` will actually give you an error message, which is more helpful than "Query failed"

Comment: I also added that. It says that the link resource is not valid. Which makes no sense, since I threw in a gettype, and that says it's a resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has an option for whether to accept `COUNT (*)` or whether to insist that there be no space.  This option can be set per database connection, so it might be set differently in your phpMyAdmin connection versus your PHP connection.

So `SELECT COUNT (*) ...` might be an error or not, depending on the SQL mode.  It's usually more correct to use `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` without the space after `COUNT`.

See [Function Name Parsing and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

remove the space between count and the brackets

```
select count(*) ...
```

then your query looks syntactially correct. are you absolutely positive you copied the exactly this sql statement into phpmyadmin and into your php code? coz my phpmyadmin doesn't like spaces between count and the brackets either...

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) from tablename LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. I removed the spaces and the query still does not execute. Also, the error is happening in the PHP code, not in phpMyAdmin